# How can I make setting up the encounter during play faster?

Tags: dnd-5e, encounters

While I was DMing, some of the players were getting frustrated with the time it took to get the stats for the enemy NPCs. Having to look at the Monster Manual for the stats of different creatures takes too long, which I am fine with, but I don't want to lose my some of my group members because of my speed. Are there any tips to increase this process? Or is it just an aspect of D&D that can't be helped?

Comment: Is there something that prevents you from making notes before play begins, or am I just not understanding your question?

Comment: Are you planning these encounters before the game session, or are these encounters the result of improvised situations that couldn't be planned for?

Comment: I've put this on hold until you can clarify what exactly is making speed a problem in this case. That's not a rejection of your question though! We just want to ensure you get answers that are helpful by being relevant to your actual problem, and we need a bit more information to fully see the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is to simply scan and print the monsters, spells, items, maneuvers and feats that you're going to use, and keeping them handy. 
Stuff them in a binder once you're done using them.
When you prepare for a new game, print those you dont already have, and just pull those you do have out of your binder.